# ListView buttons behaving strangely - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-button

I have button for every ListView item. Every button begins green or gray, depending on a JSON array. If the button begins green then once it is clicked it turns gray. If a button begins gray once its clicked it turns green. The problem is when I scroll up and out of view of the button and then back to the button it has turned back to its original color. Here is the code for my buttons,

```
if(p.JSONarray().equals("NO")){
```

button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray);

```
                 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View button) {


                        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);


                    }//end on click
                });
                }//end if equals NO
                if(p.JSONarray().equals("YES")){

                     button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);

                     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View button) {


                        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray);


                    }//end on click
                });

                }//end if equals yes
```

Why does the button go back to its original color once it goes out of view?

Comment: refer to answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20233292/827110

Answer (score 1):

The color change back to default because the views are created again. You will need to maintain a list of `Button` positions you have already clicked so that when you reach that position again in `getView` you can change the color of your Button

Comment: how can I make a list of button positions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an else condition to maintain the color of the button.
In your case your code should be like this:

```
            if(p.JSONarray().equals("YES")){

                 button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);

                 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View button) {


                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray);


                }//end on click
            });

            }else
            {
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray);
            }
```